# How to implement update and insert in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

I have Phone table with columns :

Clien_ID,Phone_num,Phone_Extention,Phone_Type,Last_Updated_Dt,Created_Dt

I am getting fixed width flat file which I will loading in staging table in sql.

I have to update the records in Phone table in terms of phone_num,Phone_Extention,Last_Updated_Dt
for each phone type (based on matching Client ID) if Last_Updated_Dt of flat file record is greater than existing Last_Updated_dt and insert a new record of phone type of client does not exist.

How can I implement in informatica.

Answer (score 1):

```
SRC->SQ->LKP->RTR->TGT_ins
                 \>UPD_upd->TGT_upd
```

The SRC is the flatfile, the LKP is against your target (match on Client_ID), the UPD_upd should be set to DD_UPDATE, and now for the 'hard' part, the router and its ports:

- all ports from the LKP should be prefixed with 'LKP_' when going into the router
- the ports from the flatfile should be prefixed with 'SRC_'
- Configure the router with two 'groups' and name the groups: Insert and Update
- The condition on the Insert group is easy: isnull(SRC_Client_ID)
- The condition on the Update group in your case is: SRC_last_Updated_dt>LKP_last_Updated_dt

Comment: I will implement this week your solution and will let you know my results and in case of issues will comment.But thanks so much

Comment: The update condition here would be used via Update Strategy transformation ?

Comment: Yes - the UPD_upd is an update strategy transformation for the 'update' data stream. The insert stream don't _need_ one, so I always omit it, but some find it better to include it... I ALWAYS use a router and different targets for ins/upd/delete, and never 'dd_reject' as a replacement for a filter/router since it gives much more useful log-data afterwards... all a matter of preference